# Is the integral of *the* complex number defined (or of any constant)?

Tags: integration

This question may be mislead (or even dumb), but is $$\int_a^b i~~di~~\text{for}~~i^2 = -1$$ defined? Maybe more generally, is $$\int_a^b n~~dn~~\text{for fixed}~~n \in \mathbb{R}$$ defined?

Comment: You integrate with respect to a variable (in terms of which the integrand is expressed as an integrable function).  Integrating "with respect to" a constant makes no sense.

Comment: You could make an argument for assigning a value of zero to such integrals via the chain rule, but that seems like a horrendous abuse of notation to me.

Comment: This could be made to have sense by interpreting it as a Riemann-Stieljes integral with respect to the constant function $i$ —and then the value is zero. Otherwise it ia just  a senseless expression, motivated only by a misunderstanding of what the differential in an integral denotes.

Comment: The strangest part of this question is the "more generally." Bizarre to think there'd be a definition for $i$ that did not work for $n$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Whoops. Good point; complex numbers are more general than real numbers. I still *think* of real numbers as the "general" number, haha.

Answer (score 2):

The notation $\displaystyle\int_a^b \cdots\cdots\,di$ implies $i$ is a variable that goes from $a$ to $b$.  Thus it is not consistent with $i$ having a fixed value, either $\sqrt{-1}$ or any other fixed number.

Answer (score 1):

Considering $d$ as an operator, the exterior derivative, if $c$ is a constant then $dc=0$. Therefore the integrals in your question evaluate to $0$.

Comment: But then the bounds of integration, $a$ and $b$, make no sense.

Comment: @MichaelHardy True, but that doesn't bother me too much for some reason. I feel this is the correct answer.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, too. $di$ would be a differential change in $i$, and—since $i$ is not changing—there would be no differential change.

Answer (score 0):

$dx$ can be understood as a very small or "differential change in $x$."

Differential change in a constant doesn't make sense because constants are not changing.